# Is there any way to tell MSVC compiler, that virtual function is never throws?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have some abstract class:

```
struct Interface
{
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
};
```

And I want to mark a pure virtual function as never throw. The MSVC compiler provides an attribute __nothrow -- this attribute tells the compiler that the declared function and the functions it calls never throw an exception.

But it seems, that it doesn't work with virtual functions: if I declare abstract class in such way

```
struct Interface
{
    virtual __nothrow void Foo() = 0;
};
```

the сompiler still consider, that Interface::Foo() can throw (it adds unnecessary SEH-frames in binary code).

Also I tried to declare function with 'throw()' and 'extern "C"' -- but the compiler still generate wrong binary code.

Is any way in MSVC compiler to declare virtual function as nothrow?

UPD: it seems, that this is a bug. Submitted it to Microsoft, [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1117863/-declspec-nothrow-doesnt-work-with-virtual-functions).

Comment: as I can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49147z04.aspx) it's `nothrow` without underscores

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc `__nothrow` is defined as a macro expanding to `__declspec(nothrow)` in Microsoft's own headers.

Comment: Why are you using `extern "C"`?

Comment: You must have a pretty old version of MSVC to still see the SEH frames getting registered in the machine code.  Try putting the attribute on the implementation function instead.

Comment: @Axalo because if source code compiled with /EHsc flag, the MSVC compiler assume, that extern "C" function can't throw any C++ exception.

Comment: @maxim.yurchuk Have you tried it without `extern "C"`?

Comment: @HansPassant "You must have a pretty old version of MSVC" -- no, I checked this on MSVC 2013 and get the same codegeneration. "Try putting the attribute on the implementation function instead." -- this make no sense, compiler couldn't know implementation of virtual function at compile time.

Comment: @Axalo "Have you tried it without extern "C"?" --Yes. I found this problem  without any additional attributes in interface.

Comment: My answer was week, but the reference useful. See http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm

Comment: does MSVC combine SEH with C++ exceptions? (in some compilers they are completely separate)

Comment: @Bathsheba actually MSVC compiler doesn't follow the standard in exception specification. If in function declared as throw()  some exception raised MSVC will not call std::unexpected. MSVC just remove any exception handling from that function and assume that this function never throws.

Comment: @MattMcNabb it depends on compilers flags. You can check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5.aspx) describing SEH and C++ exception interaction.

Comment: FWIW, it's not just with virtual functions, testing shows the same behaviour with `throw()` function pointers.

Comment: BTW ,with VS 2015 you will be able to use C++11 ``noexcept``.

Comment: Post the bug-link + a summary as an answer, and I'll upvote it.

Comment: For the record, VS2013 Nov CTP supports noexcept.